# Tool for Linux to create .desktop files

Tags: linux, desktop-environment

I find myself having to manually create a lot of `.desktop` files in order to get shortcuts to third party applications or scripts I wrote.

On Windows I used to be able to right-click any `.exe` file I want and create a shortcut from it with one click.

So what I'm looking for are Linux tools that make the process of creating `.desktop` files easier. (For example a context-menu integration or a dedicated GUI where I can easily select my target executable and have the other settings be generated automatically.)

I'm usually using Gnome or KDE in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misinterpreting your question, it is seen that every linux desktop environment has a gui to create a launcher for 3rd party software and all other apps.  The link below shows gui and commandline launcher information for many de.  In addition to the below I use mate and that also allows 3rd party desktop launchers.  Generally a right click on the desktop can be used to start the process.

https://www.xmodulo.com/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html

Start the gui and input the properties. The properties are input manually but are quite minimal.  Sometimes the "command" to actually start the app can get tricky but a little trial and error has always solved the problem.  There is then a template command for other similar apps.
Save gui and then activate from the desktop.  The guis create .desktop files in the Desktop directory.

Comment: That link must be way outdated. `gnome-desktop-item-edit` doesn't exist (at least not anymore).

Answer (score 0):

In KDE, left click the application launcher and click **Edit Applications**. [image]

Click the `New Item` to write a new application entry. You can copy the .desktop file from  `~/.local/share/applications`.

Read these AU questions: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580094/how-to-use-gui-to-create-directory), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457617/are-there-any-gui-apps-that-can-create-desktop-files).

Answer (score 0):

On ArchLinux there is a tool called [gendesk](https://github.com/xyproto/gendesk). This is a command line tool and it even pulls icons for known applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Arronax](https://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/)

> Arronax is a program to create and modify starters (technically: .desktop files) for applications and locations (URLs).

Currently (2021) it is still under active development. I have used Arronax to create a few .desktop files. However, I did not understand it fully.

> To use Arronax you need
> Gtk 3.4 or later
> GObject introspection data for the WNCK library version 3.x
> Python 3.4 or later
> PyGObject
> distribute (Python Package/Software)